# How do I set an array of arrays in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I want to set an array of arrays with NSUserDefaults like this:

```
let array = [["Mexico","USA","Canada"],["Mexico City","Washington","Ottawa"]]

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey:"Countries")
```

Then I try to access it

```
var recalledArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Countries") as! NSArray
println(recalledArray)
```

But this is what the console prints:

```
(
    "\U00bfMexico",
    "\U00bfUSA",
    "Canada"
)
```

I only get the first array, missing the second one:

```
["Mexico City","Washington","Ottawa"]
```

Why am I only getting back the first array?
How do I get back both the arrays?

Comment: your code is correct. print this way println(recalledArray[0]) and println(recalledArray[1]).

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya it's still not working if i print `recalledArray[0]` I get `Mexico`and if i print `recalledArray[1]` I get `USA`

Comment: i past your code and run see my output : (
        (
        Mexico,
        USA,
        Canada
    ),
        (
        "Mexico City",
        Washington,
        Ottawa
    )
)

Comment: i think you use old version of swift try to remove ! like this as NSArray

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya still not working it gives me an error telling me that i need to force downcast with as! NSArray

Comment: yes you were right @DharmeshDhorajiya the problem was in another part of my code as I explained in the answer, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Im so sorry there was another problem, I was checking if the app was first launched then save the NSUserDefaults if not then dont save it again so i added the second array after I runned the app on the simulator so the code was never saved to NSUserDefaults, but anyway thank you for trying to help